# Cannot import javax.ejb.* packages

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am having trouble in building an `EJB` session bean.

The following `packages` cannot be found:

```
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement; 
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
```

Some solutions implied adding the libraries `j2ee.jar` and `javaee`.jar to the java build path.

I am using `jdk-7u75-windows-x64` and `java_ee_sdk-7-windows-ml` and cannot find any of these libraries at the given location($JAVA_HOME\lib). I am using eclipse(kepler) on a `Windows 7 x64` machine

Answer (score 36, accepted):

javaee.jar ships with neither eclipse nor java(jdk). The file must be manually downloaded and added to the project build path. The java ee 7 api can be found [here.](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0) 
Alternatively, a maven dependency can be used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: come on, Java, this is not intuitive enough.

Answer (score 3):

The EJB API is found in the JavaEE libraries which are, as you correctly pointed out, distributed with the j2ee.jar library. If you're using Eclipse, its classpath may be pointing to the standard Java libraries and not the Enterprise libraries. You can try two things:

1. Compile and run your code from the command line. Set %JAVA_HOME% to point to the installation directory of java_ee_sdk-7-windows-ml and add %JAVA_HOME%/bin to the %PATH%.
2. Find the Enterprise library and add it to your CLASSPATH in Eclipse. The CLASSPATH is set by going to the project properties and selecting the option "Add an external library/jar file". Add any jar files found in the EE installation directory to the build path.