# Glassfish uses internal module libarry instead of application library

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, glassfish-4.1

I am trying to deploy a Spring boot application on Glassfish 4.1.21.
At startup I get an error that that the entityManagerFactory cannot pe created due to the fact that a method does not exist. It doas not exist because, for some reason, when the applicaiton is started on glassfish, instead of using jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar, it is used a library form inside glassfish/module bean-validator.jar. Everything works fine with embeded Tomcat.

log file

```
[2020-05-08T15:57:04.360+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.Utils] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1588942623190] [timeMillis: 1588942624360] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn]]

[2020-05-08T15:57:04.454+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.Utils] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1588942623190] [timeMillis: 1588942624454] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn]]

[2020-05-08T15:57:04.470+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.Utils] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1588942623190] [timeMillis: 1588942624470] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn]]

[2020-05-08T15:57:22.930+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1588942642930] [levelValue: 900] [[
  The web application [unknown] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.]]

  2020-05-08 15:57:40.205  WARN 8124 --- [min-listener(4)] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bmw/taeerep_data_provisioning/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration]]

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.]]

  2020-05-08 15:57:40.236 ERROR 8124 --- [min-listener(4)] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationBootstrapParameters.<init>(ValidationBootstrapParameters.java:63)

The following method did not exist:

    javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;

The method's class, javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain_taee/applications/taeerep_data_provisioning-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar!/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class
    bundle://306.0:1/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/bean-validator.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration]]

[2020-05-08T15:57:40.237+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1588942660237] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Error invoking ServletContainerInitializer org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bmw/taeerep_data_provisioning/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:6062)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5960)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationBootstrapParameters.<init>(ValidationBootstrapParameters.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:540)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:337)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:131)
    ... 79 more
]]

[2020-05-08T15:57:40.239+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-CORE-00174] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1588942660239] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Startup of context /taeerep_data_provisioning-1.0-SNAPSHOT failed due to previous errors]]

[2020-05-08T15:57:40.254+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1588942660254] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  WebModule[/taeerep_data_provisioning-1.0-SNAPSHOT]Servlet dispatcherServlet threw unload() exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.destroy() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1913)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.stop(StandardWrapper.java:2194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:6152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5981)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bmw/taeerep_data_provisioning/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5985)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bmw/taeerep_data_provisioning/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:6068)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5960)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bmw/taeerep_data_provisioning/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:6062)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationBootstrapParameters.<init>(ValidationBootstrapParameters.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:540)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:337)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:131)
    ... 79 more
]]

  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bmw/taeerep_data_provisioning/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bmw/taeerep_data_provisioning/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bmw/taeerep_data_provisioning/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bmw/taeerep_data_provisioning/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ion</groupId>
    <artifactId>taeerep_data_provisioning</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>taeerep_data_provisioning</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<!--    <build>-->
<!--        <plugins>-->
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
<!--        </plugins>-->
<!--    </build>-->

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.ion.taeerep_data_provisioning.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mvnrepository</id>
            <url>https://maven.xwiki.org/externals/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Any ideas, this SF for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Spring Boot 2.0.0 and above is not compatible with with Glassfish 4.1.2 and below. It was due to a dependeny conflict between glassfish and Spring, a dependency that is specific to Java EE 8, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59950466/5264186 . The solution was either to downgrade the dependecies versions or upgrade to Glassfish 5 which is for Java EE 8.