# javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String No such method

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am getting below exception while executing springboot application:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationBootstrapParameters.<init>(ValidationBootstrapParameters.java:63) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar!/:6.0.7.Final]'
```

I included `validation-api` as a dependency with latest version & also made sure no other version is coming (not using hibernate validator as well) Still it is failing. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: I got the same exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
 at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationBootstrapParameters.<init>(ValidationBootstrapParameters.java:61) with tags are [maven] [java ee].

Comment: have you ever found a solution?

Comment: The solution to this issue can be found [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947293/maven-using-wrong-version-of-javax-validation)

Answer (score 2):

Check the lib folder to differing version of validation-api -- for example

- jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar
- validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar

And try to see if you can remove validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar