# How to fix Java Spark Submit error: NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-spark

I am trying to run a Spring Boot application on a Spark master using the following command:

```
spark-submit --master spark://IP-Address:Port --conf spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true --executor-memory 20G --total-executor-cores 100 JAR_PATH
```

The pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-rdd-join-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spark RDD Join</name>
    <description>Demo project for RDD Spark Join</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spark core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spark Sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spark Cassandra Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Needed for the Cassandra connection with Spark, otherwise connection 
            error -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.spark.join.SparkRddJoinApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.jav
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:49
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)t.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:14
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)n.java:398)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)dJoinApplication.java:22)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)r.java:51)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)t$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933).scala:924)
 at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationBootstrapParameters.<init>(ValidationBootstrapParameters.java:63)

Caused by at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:540)ng/String;
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:309)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)58)
        ... 36 more
```

I already searched details about this error, but  I still haven't found a solution for it. I already tried adding and removing dependencies, I added spark configuration properties.

It seems that I am stuck at this error.

Did someone deal with this problem and have a solution? Please help...

I saw some solutions related with Hibernate dependencies, but I am not using Hibernate in my project...

I am trying to perform a join over two Cassandra tables with Spark...

Comment: Please post your Hibernate config.

Comment: I do not work with Hibernate in my project...

Comment: See the stack trace: `org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml`. Obviously you are using Hibernate, directly or indirectly. If indirectly, may be it it used in Spark. Check Spark configs.

Comment: Oh, yes! I found it... It was a dependency express through spring-boot-starter-web.. I excluded it, but now it gives me the following error:

Description:

The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found

Action:

Add an implementation, such as Hibernate Validator, to the classpath
.....It somehow fixed the previous error but created another one..

Comment: What have you removed? Try to understand what are you doing, why do you have particular library, why do you have this library in a particular version.

Comment: The solution to this issue can be found [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947293/maven-using-wrong-version-of-javax-validation)

Answer (score 0):

You have compiled your code with Java EE 8, but trying to run on in Java EE environment. The interface `BootstrapConfiguration` existed also in the Java EE 7, but the method `getClockProviderClassName` was added only in Java EE 8.

Comment: I checked, the Java version on the Spark Master is the same as on my computer where I compiled  my project.